# Make a field unique in one schema but not unique in other schemas with MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoDB with Mongoose to build an API.

I have two (maybe more soon) schemas:

```
user : {
    name : String,
    email : {
        required: true,
        unique : true
    }
}
```

and

```
ticket : {
     title : String,
     author : userModel.schema,
}
```

Every user must have a unique email because they will use it as login credential.
Every user can write a ticket, each time a ticket is sent, I add in the author field, the user object that has written the ticket.

Each user can as of now write only one ticket, if I try a second one I have this error :

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: BTB_DB.tickets index: author.email_1 dup key: { : "email@email.com"}
```

I found out that Mongo actually creates an index for the tickets that ensures that the author.email unique, see below a screenshot of my mongo compass:

[image: mongocompass]

That index is also only present for the tickets collection, not for the user collection?
Where does that index come from?

My question is : is it possible to keep the email field unique in the user schema but not unique in other schemas?

If not is there another way to nest the user in the tickets? I tried only a little with userId and mongoose's populate methold, should I invest more time on that solution? I really want to keep the user in the ticket.

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can unique email in user collection but not other collections

Comment: @NuOne but there where does the index on author.email come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define author in ticket as below

```
ticket : {
     title : String,
     author : {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
}
```

when you are getting ticket if you want to get the user that ticket belongs to use populate() like this,

```
Ticket.find().populate('author');
```

and also when you are creating a ticket make sure to provide the _id of the user for author field

```
new Ticket({'title': 'title of the ticket', 'author':'_idOfTheUser'})
```

Comment: I tried it, I got this error :
    E11000 duplicate key error collection: BTB_DB.tickets index: author.email_1 dup key: { : null }

edit: i droped the collection, recreated it with a ticket creation, it created the index again but it s working as of now. Thanks!